# Link targets should not count into the comment length

Tags: feature-request, comments, formatting

When posting a comment, one is limited to 500 characters. These include the link target addresses, which can be pretty long. I believe that the intention of the restriction is to make the comment at most 500 printed characters. Therefore, for instance the following comment should count as only 3 characters:

```
[MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)
```

Comment: One thing we can do is cut down the URL length. For example, `http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228` will work equally well in the given example.

Comment: @JosephWright: Even `http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228` will suffice.

Comment: Thanks friends, at least some help. Still, I think the request is reasonable.